# Downloading from Google Drive returns 403 Forbidden after a while

Tags: google-drive-api, dotnetopenauth

I am downloading files with a ASP Web Application from Google Drive, using a service account, OpenAuth2 and a .p12 key file.
This works great, but after a while (10-12x downloading), it fails with a ProtocolException.
The inner exception is: "The remote server returned 403 Forbidden".
After about 3 minutes, the downloads succeed again(!).

Can anyone explain what is happening, and more importantly, how to fix this problem?